# Netlogo: How to make a patch find the closest turtle after its previous turtle died

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I have set of conditions when met a turtle will die. When a turtle dies, in the same tick i want the patches to find their new closest turtle. I have written the following code

```
to party-death
  ask parties [ if ( my-size = 0 and count parties > 2) 
[ die ask patches [set closest-party min-one-of parties [distance myself]]
  ]]
```

The problem is the tick at which a turtle dies, the patches for whom the dead turtle was the closest dont find the next closest turtle in the same tick.

I have another sub-routine defined as follows which is throwing the an error since the closest-turtle for one of the patches in the agentset is dead:

```
to citizen-comparison
 let voter-patches patches with [votes-with-benefit != 0]
 let nonvoter-patches patches with [votes-with-benefit = 0]
 ask voter-patches [ set voter-peccentricity [eccentricity] of closest-party]
 ask nonvoter-patches [ set nonvoter-peccentricity [eccentricity] of closest-party]

That party is dead.
error while patch 0 32 running OF
  called by procedure CITIZEN-COMPARISON
  called by procedure ELECTION
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Go once'
```

How to avoid this error by asking the patches to choose their new closest turtle in the same tick in which their old closest-turtle died.

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work? I have just moved the brackets so that the `die` is completed then the find

```
to party-death
  ask parties [ if ( my-size = 0 and count parties > 2) [ die ] ]
  ask patches [set closest-party min-one-of parties [distance myself]]
```

Comment: It works. I remember trying that but didn't work at that time. Nonetheless, thanks for the help.